# Is it possible to see who were the "Public Views" that viewed my Careers account?

Tags: support, jobs, profile-page

I have my profile in http://careers.stackoverflow.com/ and in this page in the right side of the page under "Your Profile"  it is showing "Public Views" as 8.
I would like to see who viewed my profile, is it possible to see this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this feature is available, usually on Stack Exchange sites you cannot see who interact with you except for comment and answers which are associated to the user.

I totally agree with this approach because it avoids the generation of a sort of "chain of revenge" in which if you downvote my questions/answer I downvote yours and so on.

Talking about the career profile I think that a nice idea could be to send a notification to the user who has submitted a job application only if the recruiter has seen the submitted CV. This feature could be very useful (I asked for it [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263376/is-there-a-way-to-know-if-a-recruiter-on-stack-overflow-careers-has-seen-your-cv/263395#263395)) but I would not extend this to the Public Views.

Comment: The answer for your last para is here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/263395/254554

Comment: Yea, I know and I've added the link ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the edit. You got my +1 there and here too :)